# load interstitial ad on IBAction button

Tags: ios, swift, admob, interstitial

When my callButton is clicked it rings a phone number, I want to display my interstitial ad before the call is made. I have tested my ad on the "IBAction function ad" button and it works on the button but when I call it on the callButton func it will not work and goes straight to making a call.

```
class ProfilePageViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate {

@IBAction func ad(_ sender: Any) {
    if self.interstitialAd.isReady {
        self.interstitialAd.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
}

@IBAction func callButton(_ sender: Any) {

    if let contactopt = contact{

        if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(contactopt)") {
            //    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
            UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}

var interstitialAd: GADInterstitial!

func reloadInterstitialAd() -> GADInterstitial {
    var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-/6966780536")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.load(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    self.interstitialAd = reloadInterstitialAd()
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    interstitialAd = reloadInterstitialAd()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.interstitialAd = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-/6966780536")
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
    self.interstitialAd.load(request)
    self.interstitialAd = reloadInterstitialAd()

    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it goes to making a call. That's what you're telling it to do with `UIApplication.shared.open`.

Make the call once the ad has been dismissed in `interstitialDidDismissScreen`.
Also check to see if there is an ad to present, `interstitialAd.isReady`. If there is no ad to present go straight to making the call.

You're also doing the same thing twice in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
// Sets up an ad
self.interstitialAd = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-/6966780536")
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
self.interstitialAd.load(request)
// Creates a new ad
self.interstitialAd = reloadInterstitialAd()
```

Just call `self.interstitialAd = reloadInterstitialAd()`.

Comment: do you suggest I leave the "IBAction function ad" how it is to show a full page ad, and calling my callButton function in the interstitialDidDismissScreen function?

Comment: @hghg I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem has to do with the synchrony of the `present` method on the interstitial. I do not know what the implementation is, but it seems like the ad's presentation does not block the thread on which it was called. You should try implementing `GADInterstitialDelegate` to grab the event when the ad is presented then proceed to make your call from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> GADInterstitial is a one time use object. That means once an
>   interstitial is shown, hasBeenUsed returns true and the interstitial
>   can't be used to load another ad. To request another interstitial,
>   you'll need to create a new GADInterstitial object. The best practice,
>   as shown above, is to have a helper method to handle creating and
>   loading an interstitial.

```
func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
  var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
  interstitial.delegate = self
  interstitial.load(GADRequest())
  return interstitial
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
  interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}

@IBAction func ad(_ sender: Any) {
    if self.interstitialAd.isReady {
        self.interstitialAd.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
}
```